# A generic error occurred in GDI+ upon saving an Image using Spire Presentation API

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I am using Spire Presentation API to convert PowerPoint slides into image but while saving the image "A generic error occurred in GDI+." exception is thrown. I am not able carve out any idea to overcome this exception.

Below is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Drawing;
using Spire.Presentation;
using Spire.Presentation.Drawing;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
          Presentation presentation = new Presentation();
          presentation.LoadFromFile("d:\\slide.pptx");
          System.Drawing.Image image=presentation.Slides[0].SaveAsImage();
          string fileName = String.Format("slider1.png", 0);
          image.Save(fileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
          System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fileName);
       }
}
```

During execution when

```
image.Save(fileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

is executed then "A generic error occurred in GDI+" exception is thrown

Comment: Is there an inner exception?

Comment: No there is no inner exception.

Comment: What are the `image` dimensions at the `.Save` point?

Comment: it seems that the value of variable fileName is incorrect. Please change it and have a try.